# Rails 3 Subdomain Testing Using lvh.me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I've been looking at the [Railscast Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) to get started with adding a sub-domain to my Rails application and he mentions that localhost:3000 won't play nicely with subdomains so instead we use lvh.me:

> If we go to http://lvh.me:3000/ we’ll see the homepage of our
>   application because lvh.me resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1.

Well my application is running in WEBrick under development mode on 127.0.0.1 and navigating to that link doesn't bring me to my application, instead I'm greeted with:

> Firefox can't find the server at www.lvh.me.

I've also tried http://lvh.me/, & http://xyz.lvh.me:3000/ with no dice.

Is this just a problem on my end or is lvh.me out of commission nowadays? If so are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Domains go down? Who knew! Well at least that seems to be the case as it's now working as expected.